# "Failed to trigger translation for this file." error when uploading a .zip file for the translation job

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

What I'm doing is uploading a .zip file and creating a translation job. The .zip file contains several .CATPART files and one .CATPRODUCT file.

bellow is my payload

```
{
    "input": {
        "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6emlwX2ZpbGVzX3Rlc3RpbmcvQU1GMV8wNC56aXA",
        "rootFilename": "17J20-0851---B.1.CATProduct",
        "compressedUrn": true
    },
    "output": {
        "destination": {
            "region": "us"
        },
        "formats": [
            {
                        "type": "stl",
                        "advanced": 
                        {
                          "format" : "binary",
                          "exportColor":true,
                          "exportFileStructure" : "single"
                        }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but I'm keep getting the error **"Failed to trigger translation for this file."**.

I even tried uploading and translation using the provided [postman collection](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-tutorial-postman/blob/master/ModelDerivative_01/readme.md) but the result is same

However i tried uploading the whole folder(not as a zip of course) to the [Autodesk viewer](https://viewer.autodesk.com/) and it works. So i dont think there is an issue in the set of files.
What could be the reason ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the list of supported translations here:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/

Unfortunately, you cannot translate a CATPART/CATPRODUCT to STL - you can only get a thumbnail, SVF, or SVF2 from it

Once you translated it to SVF, you'll also be able to get OBJ from it. This option is available for all file formats.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with the help of @Adam's  reply ,

So i changed the type to "svf"

```
 "type": "stl"
```

and added the views

```
  "views": [
             "2d",
              "3d"
           ]
```

and it worked .

my final payload would be ,

```
{
    "input": {
        "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6emlwX2ZpbGVzX3Rlc3RpbmcvQU1GMV8wNS56aXA",
        "rootFilename": "17J20-0851---B.1.CATProduct",
        "compressedUrn": true
    },
    "output": {
        "destination": {
            "region": "us"
        },
        "formats": [
            {
                        "type": "svf2",
                        "advanced": 
                        {
                          "format" : "binary",
                          "exportColor":true,
                          "exportFileStructure" : "single"
                        },
                        "views": [
                            "2d",
                            "3d"
                        ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone in future .